# Update a SQLite3 database using CSVs and script automation

Tags: python, ruby, csv, cmd, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that is populated with values from csv files. I would like to create a script that when run:

1. deletes the old tables
2. creates new tables with the same schema (with newly updated values)

I noticed that sqlite script files don't accept ".mode csv" or .import "csv". Is there a way to automate this is with a script of some sort?

Comment: Not clear, but I suppose you should use some gems, for example `require "csv"` and `require "sqlite3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Python approach, you can use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method from the `pandas` package to write to SQLite. Pandas can replace existing tables and automatically generate the schema based on the CSV file read.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')

# read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")

# write to SQLite
df.to_sql("my_tbl", conn, if_exists="replace")

conn.close()
```

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for!